# Play2 Map Objects in template

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a play2 Project and I want to create an new Product. A Product includes a KeyInfo which is stored in a several Table.

This is my tempalte for an new Product

```
@(newProductForm:Form[models.Product], keyInfoList: List[Keyinfo] )
@adminMain(""){
@helper.form(action = routes.Admin.insertNewProduct()) {

    @helper.inputText(
        newProductForm("name"),
        'label -> "name",
        'type -> "name"
    )

    @helper.inputText(
        newProductForm("price"),
        'label -> "price",
        'type -> "price"
    )

    @helper.inputText(
        newProductForm("shortDescription"),
        'label -> "shortDescription",
        'type -> "shortDescription"
    )

    @helper.inputText(
        newProductForm("description"),
        'label -> "description",
        'type -> "description"
    )


    @helper.select(
    newProductForm("keyinfo"),
    helper.options(
        for(info <- keyInfoList) yield info.keyinformation

        )
    )

    <button type="submit">Add</button>
 }
}
```

The select helper for the keyinfo is getting all Fieldnames correctly from the Table. The Problem is now, that the id for the KeyInformation is not stored in the ProductTable.

Here is the Controller function to save a Product

```
    public static Result insertNewProduct() {
    Form<Product> productForm = form(Product.class).bindFromRequest();
    return ok(showNewProduct.render(Product.create(productForm.get())));

    }
```

And the Product model with the create function

```
@Entity
public class Product extends Model {

@Id
//@Constraints.Required
//@Formats.NonEmpty
@Column(name="id")
public Integer id;

@Constraints.Required
public String name;

@Constraints.Required
public Float price;

@Constraints.Required
@Column(name="short_Description")
public String shortDescription;

@Constraints.Required
public String description;

@ManyToOne
@Constraints.Required
public Keyinfo keyinfo;



public static Product create(Product product){
    product.save();
    return product;
}
```

I hope that somebody can help me

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the root cause without seeing the whole project, but to help you find the issue, you can dump debug messages to check values while you attempt the save:

```
public static Product create(Product product){
    play.Logger.info("Saving ... product name: " + product.name);
    play.Logger.info("Saving ... product key info: " + product.keyinfo.toString());
    ... 
    product.save();
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I had a look for the Product-Object. After adding the new product from the form the Product-Objects has a reference to the Keyinfo. Here is the problem, that the keyinfo-Object just includes the keyinfo.name and not the Keyinfo.id (the Keyinfo Model has aname and an id) thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ebean you may need to explicitly save keyInfo first then set product.keyInfo and save the product.